# Add an array at the end of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have to add some elements from an array into another array for a project.

Here's the deal: I have 2 arrays, from 2 tables of a database, which are named `$stand` and `$signal`.

`$stand` is made up of arrays:

```
$stand = [[id, name, width, length,...], [id, name, width, length,...], ...]
```

`$signal` is made up of arrays as well:

```
$signal = [[id, num, name, adress, ...], [id, num, name, adress, ...], ...]
```

Each entry of `$stand` matches with an entry of `$signal`: the id of an entry of `$stand` is equal to the number of elements in `$signal`.

For these entries, I'd like to add the content of the entry of `$signal` at the end of the entry of `$stand`.

Here's the code I used, but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
foreach ($stand as $st) {
   foreach ($signal as $sig) {
      if ($st[0] == $sig[1]) {
         $st[]=$sig;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [**array_push**](http://in2.php.net/array_push).

Comment: May I suggest to make it via SQL?

Comment: @Rikesh : I did (array_push($st,$sig); instead of $st[]=$sig;) but it didn't work either.

Comment: regarding your code, you would want to add to array `$stand` not to its elements. Better approach is `array_merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($stand as $key => $st) {
   foreach ($signal as $sig) {
      if ($st[0] == $sig[1]) {
         $stand[$key][]=$sig;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It worked with this solution! Sorry about that question btw, i'm a beginner in PHP.

Comment: The solution is correct but you should try to avoid copying the code without understanding (unless you do understand what he did their). And Paul, it would be great if you mentioned why you did what you did :).

Comment: When I saw this answer, I've searched about that '$key =>' code, because I didn't learned it. And I realized I made a huge mistake using $st in my condition instead of $stand.

Answer (score 8):

array_merge is the elegant way:

```
$a = array('a', 'b');
$b = array('c', 'd');
$merge = array_merge($a, $b); 
// $merge is now equals to array('a','b','c','d');
```

Doing something like:

```
$merge = $a + $b;
// $merge now equals array('a','b')
```

Will not work, because the + operator does not actually merge them. If they $a has the same keys as $b, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Use array_merge function.

```
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

For more detail [read here](https://www.php.net/array_merge)

Answer (score 0):

$st seems to be a copy of an element array, but not an element reference. So modifications you make to $st are lost.
Thus you should precede $st with an ampersand to use it as a reference:

`foreach($stand as &$st)`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want something like this

```
$array1 = array(array('id'=>1,'name'=>'manish'),array('id'=>2,'name'=>'bhuvnesh'));

$array2 = array(array('id'=>1,'color'=>'red'),array('id'=>2,'color'=>'green'));

$newArray = array();

foreach($array1 as $key => $vals) {
    $id = $vals['id'];
    $color = $array2[$key]['color'];
    $newArray[] = array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>$vals['name'], 'color'=>$color);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
```

This will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => manish
            [color] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => bhuvnesh
            [color] => green
        )

)
```